# Javascript: How can I join all links (array)

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML like :

```
<div id="divid">
  <a href="d#link1">1</a>
    <a href="d#link2">2</a>
    <a href="d#link3">3</a>
    .....................
</div>
```

I used script below to join, but it cannot join. Check for me.

```
var links = document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i] = links[i].href;
}
document.write('<div class="' + links.join(" ") + '">Class is added links</div>');
```

It means after joining I have HTML :

```
<div class="d#link1 d#link2 d#link3">Class is added links</div>
```

Comment: while your use case is totally not valid see my answer below.
You cannot have classes containing "#" since they're used to reference ids in css...

Comment: @LJ_1102:just for demo :)

Comment: @codehorse: of course. but I need to convert to class format and get only category :) (not all links as above. it is just for demo.)

Comment: This is the problem links[i] = links[i].href;

Answer (score 2):

```
var as = document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('a');
var links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
  links[i] = as[i].href;
}
// work with links here

console.log('<div class="' + links.join(" ") + '">Class is added links</div>');
```

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LmV56/).

Note that this causes trouble because the links are fully resolved, relative to the current domain. You might want to use another attribute to contain the classes.

Answer (score 1):

> Check for me.

Check it yourself.

document.getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList not an array, you'll need to
transform the nodelist into an array or just use a new array where you put in the hrefs...

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new variable:

```
var links = document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    hrefs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    hrefs[i] = links[i].href;
}

document.write('<div class="' + hrefs.join(" ") + '">Class is added links</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a separate array to hold the links.

Something like:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var linkarr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    linkarr[i] = links[i].href;
}
document.write('<div class="' + linkarr.join(" ") + '">Class is added links</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery:

```
var links = $('#divid').children('a');
var linkArr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  linksArr += links[i].attr('href') + ' ';
}
document.write('<div class="' + linksArr + '">Class is added links</div>');
```